# Start Undertale fresh, without any decisions

Tags: undertale

I told a friend of mine to play Undertale, but as he doesn't have a PC, I will let him play the game on my pc.
The problem is... I already completed the game in genocide, but from what I hear, there will be save files left even after the "true" reset with %appdata%.
Someone on Reddit even said it stores Registy files on Windows...
On another question found here, they mentioned "UndertaleGenocideRemover", but do that actually work?
I don't want that the game remembers some decision and ruins the gameplay of my friend. I want that he can experience the game as a whole, with a clean, fresh start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Undertale Wiki](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#Consequence_Avoidance)

> **Save Locations**
>
> Default save locations are as follows:
>
> - *Windows:*   * *Windows XP:* %SystemDrive%/Documents and Settings/%USERNAME%/Local/Application Data/UNDERTALE   * *Windows
>     Vista/7/8/10:* %LOCALAPPDATA%/UNDERTALE
> - *Linux:*   * *DRM-free:* ~/.config/UNDERTALE_linux   * *Steam:* ~/.config/UNDERTALE_linux_steamver
> - *Mac:* ~/Library/Application Support/com.tobyfox.undertale/
>
> **Modifying/Deleting Files**
>
> To return to a playable state, the player can enter their save data
>   folder and either:
>
> - Delete the last directory in the aforementioned save location for your respective system; this removes everything you have done in the
>     game as if it is your first time playing it
> - Delete or rename the files `system_information_962` and `system_information_963` in the aforementioned save
>     location. This removes any effects of having done the Genocide Route.
>     The `system_information_962` file is the one that you have
>     erased the world, and `system_information_963` is when you
>     have sold your soul.
> - Uninstall the game and do a fresh reinstall. GOG players using GOG Galaxy may need to disable cloud saving before carrying out any of
>     these steps. Also, these methods are not sufficient for players of the
>     Steam version, as the Steam Cloud backs up the acquisition of the
>     system_information files and restores them if deleted (even if cloud
>     synchronization is disabled). Players of the Steam version have to
>     delete their Steam Cloud cache as stated
>     [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784),
>     or render the system_information files unreadable by ''Undertale'' by
>     modifying their security settings under file properties to deny read
>     permission.
> - The [Undertale Genocide Remover](http://fucknohtml.tumblr.com/post/133037946850/do-you-own-the-steam-version-of-undertale-do-you)
>     application automatically removes all Genocide Route files, even those
>     in Steam, when "ERASE" is pressed.